# math expression for scipy.stats.wald.pdf?

Tags: python, scipy

I was using `scipy.stats.wald.fit` to fit my data array and, without any warnings or errors, I got two parameters (-1.004123, 0.11517). I plot the distribution plot and the histogram plot and found them match well.

However, there are negative values in my data and wald distribution should only work for positive values, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution. How this `scipy.stats.wald.fit` works? Can anyone give me the mathematical expression of the `scipy.stats.wald.pdf`?

I actually would like to write the wald pdf function in Cuda-C, so a mathematical expression is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are location and scale parameters, here's a [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html).

Use `stats.wald.pdf(x, loc=-1.004123, scale=0.11517)` or just plug `(x - loc)/scale` into the formula which @Hugh Bothwell found for you.

```
>>> data = stats.wald.rvs(-1.004123, 0.11517, size=1000)
>>> res = stats.wald.fit(data)  # cheating, I know
>>> x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 100)
>>> ax.plot(x, stats.wald.pdf(x, *res), 'r-')
>>> ax.plot(x, stats.wald.pdf(x, loc=res[0], scale=res[1]), 'b--')
>>> ax.hist(data, normed=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3)
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: plug `(x-loc)/scale` into the formula. This is what I need! And it seems to be the way how it works for all the `pdf` functions in `scipy.stats` with the `loc` and `scale` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, look at [the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/stats/distributions.py)!

Line 5900..5906 says

```
The probability density function for `wald` is::

    wald.pdf(x, a) = 1/sqrt(2*pi*x**3) * exp(-(x-1)**2/(2*x))

for ``x > 0``.

`wald` is a special case of `invgauss` with ``mu == 1``.
```

Comment: I noticed this. However, my question is how to plug in the two parameters given through fitting.                                    And another thing is that, my data contains negative value, which makes no sense in this expression.

Comment: (+1) for the recommendation. Sadly, there's a typo in the `wald` docstring: it should be `wald.pdf(x)` --- cf line 5913 :-).